# Can not get Angularjs ng-include to work with web api mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

This is what I have in Index.cshtml

```
<div  ng-show="tab.isSet(1)"  ng-include ="'show-employees.html'">      
</div>
```

this is the show-employees.html

```
<h2>List of Employees</h2>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Department</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td>{{employee.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Position}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Salary}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.Department}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[PrintScreen of the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYVYv.png)

I am trying to include the show-employees.html tab in the index.html file but i keep getting a 404 error.I reckon the link is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ng-include as follows:

```
<div ng-include="template.url"></div>
```

Comment: i need to include show-employees.html. there is a print screen of my solution in the post

Answer (score 0):

Your html lives at views/home/show-employees.html

You will need to use the whole path, because it is a static file, so won't go through the MVC routing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access HTML files in the Views folder for MVC project.

Try the following to see if it's working for you,

1. create a view for the template in the Views/Home folder - ShowEmployees.cshtml
2. in the Home controller, add

   public ActionResult ShowEmployees()
   {
       return View();
   }
3. ng-include ="'/Home/ShowEmployees'"